# make wordpress built in login form work only if some custom usermeta is set

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 extra user roles for my users to choose when register (role1, role2). for every user when register I save 2 usermeta fields: email_status and user_status. after registration submission, an email is sent to user with an unique code (or link) to verify his/her email (email_status = false/true). but still administrators must verify the user (user_status = false/true). (I am okay with how to handle these)

to handle the login process, I made a custom login form (example.com/login). when user submit the form, I check these 2 usermeta fields to check if both are true (I find them by username). and if both are true I let user to login. so if one is false, an error message appears that say the user "your email is not verified yet OR you are not verified by admin yet, so you can not login" (only role1 and role2 can login via this form).

I have changed built in worpress login url to something else for security issues, but still i am concerned if somebody (role1 or role2) can find it and use that form for logging in. as you know this form will not check the email_status and user_status usermetas so a not-verified user can login and read the data which must not! I think about some solutions:
1. completely disable built in login form (I do not know how?!).
2. change built in login form functionality to check email_status and user_status before logging in as my custom login form(I do not know how?!).
3. set a session ($_SESSION['email_status'] = true & $_SESSION['user_status'] = true) after login for verified users (in custom login form) and before showing any limited data to them check the session if are true or not. so, because the built in login form does not set these sessions; so i can distinguish between them (I know how.).

- is the 3rd solution secure enough?
- how can i completely disable built in login form or change it's functionality to meet my requirements?

thanks